# javascript function inside jquery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Seems I am having some issues calling a javascript function inside a jquery template.  I've got a demo set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/SXvsZ/8/

Code looks like:

```
function htmlDetail(){
   return "hello <strong>world</strong>"; 
}

var book = [
    { title: "Goodnight, World!",
  detail: { author: "Jojo Mojo", synopsis : "What the ..." }},
{ title: "Rainbow",
  detail: { author: "Cookie", synopsis : "Huh?" }}
];

$("#testTemplate").tmpl(book).appendTo("#bookList");
```

and the template looks like:

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if title.length}}
      <h3>${title}</h3>
      <p>Start: ${ htmlDetail() } :End</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>

<div id="bookList"></div>
```

Seems like it should render "hello **world**" I'd like to have it also render the HTML as html and not plain text.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even know jquery had this :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To render html inside the template from another function, you will need to use the {{html}} template tag.

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if title.length}}
      <h3>${title}</h3>
      <p>Start: {{html htmlDetail() }} :End</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

You should also move the htmlDetail function outside of your ready() function

Answer (score 2):

Getting back to your question, the problem seems to be that `htmlDetail` needs to be defined before template itself. (their examples 'suggest' that)

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/SXvsZ/9/

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/

**Note** this are the beta version anyways so they are not finalised and most likely might change or even be deprecated so don't rely on that too much as of yet ofcourse but do experiment with it :)

Comment: Link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the a non global function to the template to make it avialbale inside the template, if you choose not to make it global.

```
$("#testTemplate").tmpl(book, {htmlDetail : htmlDetail} ).appendTo("#bookList");
```

it can be used like this, {{html}} will render it with no encoding

```
 <p>Start: {{html $item.htmlDetail() }} :End</p>
```